# Exception on Response.End();

Tags: c#, asp.net

I got exception on `Response.End();` and the error was:

> Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a
>   native frame is on top of the call stack

Any idea to handle this? I am using VS2008, thanks.

Comment: I don't think that's the exception. That sounds like an error you get when you try to inspect an expression in the debugger. Look for other error messages, can you see any more?

Answer (score 5):

[`HttpResponse.End`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.end.aspx) is *documented* to throw a `ThreadAbortException`. That's the point of it. As noted, it's not a great API to use in general - but the fact that it's throwing an exception isn't a problem.

The error you're seeing is actually just a failure to get at relevant information when debugging - that's not the exception that's been thrown.